# nvidia-smi not working with quadro T500

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I got a brand new Thinkpad P14s (with ubuntu 20.04.4 and) with an Intel and a NVIDIA Quadro T500 GPU installed. I want to install my nvidia drivers and later cuda, but I'm stuck: `nvidia-smi` is not working,
error is

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I tried different driver versions, different installation techniques and what ever other solution the internet has to offer, including disabling secure boot.

also `dkms status` returns `nvidia, 470.103.01: added`  but not `installed`

lshw -c display returns

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:bd000000-bdffffff memory:6040000000-604fffffff memory:6050000000-6051ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Can somebody tell me what's up and how to resolve this?

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? Show me the output of `sudo dkms build nvidia/470.103.01` and `dpkg -l *linux-* | grep ii`.

Comment: And also `dpkg -l *build-ess* make`

Comment: @heynnema thanks, that pointed me into the right direction!

Comment: Would you please share if your laptop is causing troubles or any discomfort with respect to heat/temperatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was missing a linux header file that was needed for the communication with the NVIDIA driver.

This is probably a very specific problem since while setting up my Ubuntu, I needed to install some custom other drivers because my hardware setup was not supported out of the box.

While trying to do `sudo dkms build nvidia/470.103.01` I got the error message that the specific kernel header was not installed.
Checking  `dpkg -l *linux-* | grep ii` showed me that the respective image was there but the header wasn't.

Thus, installing `sudo apt install linux-headers-...` was the only thing I was missing.

So thanks to @heynnema to pointing me into the right direction!